plot interaction between a categorical and a continuous variable
I am interested in plotting an interaction between a categorical and a continuous variable using metafor.
I tried separate plots using regplot to illustrate each factor-level, but I am wondering how to illustrate the interaction in one plot on a common x-axis?
There might also be options without using regplot. Below is what I tried so far.
Thank you very much.
Liso
library(metafor)
library(rms)
dat <- dat.bcg

#Fitting the meta-analysis
dat <- escalc(measure="RR", ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat)

#Fit a multivariable meta-regression with interaction between alloc and ablat 
res <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ alloc:ablat-1, data=dat)

reg1<-regplot(res, mod=1, las=1, digits=1, bty="l", xlab="Predictor", main="Term 1", transf=exp, xlim = c(0,60), predlim = c(0,60))
reg2<-regplot(res, mod=2, las=1, digits=1, bty="l", xlab="Predictor", main="Term 2", transf=exp, xlim = c(0,60), predlim = c(0,60))
reg3<-regplot(res, mod=3, las=1, digits=1, bty="l", xlab="Predictor", main="Term 3", transf=exp, xlim = c(0,60), predlim = c(0,60))

In response to Wolfgang's helpful comment, I tried the following code. In addition, I wondered how we would interpret the differences in the interaction terms "ablat * alloc" versus "ablat:alloc-1". I edited the code as follows:
### fit a model with an interaction between a quantitative and a categorical predictor
res <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ ablat * alloc, data=dat)
res

### draw bubble plot but do not add regression line or CI
tmp <- regplot(res, mod="ablat", xlab="Absolute Latitude", xlim=c(0,60), pred=FALSE, ci=FALSE)

### add regression lines for the three alloc levels
xs <- seq(0, 60, length=100)
preds <- predict(res, newmods=cbind(xs, 0, 0, 0, 0))
lines(xs, preds$pred, lwd=3,,col="lightblue")
preds <- predict(res, newmods=cbind(xs, 1, 0, xs, 0))
lines(xs, preds$pred, lwd=3,col="deepskyblue2")
preds <- predict(res, newmods=cbind(xs, 0, 1, 0, xs))
lines(xs, preds$pred, lwd=3,col="deepskyblue4")


### fit a model with an interaction between a quantitative and a categorical predictor, 
### BUT DIFFERENT INTERACTION TERM
resx <- rma(yi, vi, mods = ~ ablat : alloc-1, data=dat)
resx

### draw bubble plot but do not add regression line or CI
tmp <- regplot(res, mod="ablat", xlab="Absolute Latitude", xlim=c(0,60), pred=FALSE, ci=FALSE)

### add regression lines for the three alloc levels
xs <- seq(0, 60, length=100)
preds <- predict(resx, newmods=cbind(xs, 0, 0))
lines(xs, preds$pred, lwd=3,col="lightblue")
preds <- predict(resx, newmods=cbind(0, xs, 0))
lines(xs, preds$pred, lwd=3,col="deepskyblue2")
preds <- predict(resx, newmods=cbind(0, 0, xs))
lines(xs, preds$pred, lwd=3,col="deepskyblue4")


There is an example in the documentation for the function (https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/regplot.html#examples) showing how to put the three regression lines into the same plot using lines(). Why not do that?
